# TapGestureRecognizer doesn't work for view inside CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, nib, uitapgesturerecognizer, collectionview

[image]

I have the UIView that contains tapGestureRezognizer.
This view is added inside UIView in UICollectionViewCell (@IBOutlet weak var addViewContainer: UIView!)
[image]

And then I'm filing the cell and placing this AddStoreView inside the cell (AddStoreView UI is created via nib)
[image]

But when I tap on the AddStoreView object the method func tap(sender: AnyObject?) never calls. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in your `AddStoreView.awakeFromNib` does it get hit?  If you put touch event delegate methods inside your `AddStoreView` do they get called?

Comment: Yes, AddStoreView.awakefromnib is called
this code is executed
  let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddStoreView.tap(_:)))
  tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
  self.userInteractionEnabled = true
  self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

but, when I tap on the view 
func tap(sender: AnyObject?) {
isn't called

Comment: Add touch methods into that view.  Make sure the touch events are not getting swallowed by another view.

Comment: You are adding a new "AddStoreView" every time a cell becomes visible. That is definitely not correct, you should only do that when a new CollectionViewCell is created. Whether it will solve your problem, I don't know.

Comment: Most likely, the "addViewContainer" has zero size, because it does not contain any view to start with. If it does not resize automatically, then you cannot tap on anything in it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not correct, but it doesn't cause the problem.
addViewContainer doesn't have zero size, it's size if defined in xib file for Cell class.

Comment: I see AddStoreView inside cell, but tapping the view doesn't call assigned method